# Push inside forEach with query not working properly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I'm working with mongodb stitch/realm and I'm trying to modify objects inside an array with a foreach and also pushing ids into a new array.

For each object that i'm modifying, I'm also doing a query first, after the document is found I start modifying the object and then pushing the id into another array so I can use both arrays later.

The code is something like this:

```
exports = function(orgLoc_id, data){
    var HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');  
    // Access DB
    const db_name = context.values.get("database").name;
    const db = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db(db_name);
    const orgLocPickupPointCollection = db.collection("organizations.pickup_points");
    const orgLocStreamsCollection = db.collection("organizations.streams");
    const streamsCollection = db.collection("streams");
      
    let stream_ids = [];    
  
    data.forEach(function(stream) {
  
      return streamsCollection.findOne({_id: stream.stream_id}, {type: 1, sizes: 1}).then(res => { //if I comment this query it will push without any problem
        if(res) {
          let newId = new BSON.ObjectId();
          stream._id = newId;
          stream.location_id = orgLoc_id;
          stream.stream_type = res.type;
          stream.unit_price = res.sizes[0].unit_price_dropoff;
          stream._created = new Date();
          stream._modified = new Date();
          stream._active = true; 
    
          stream_ids.push(newId);
                              
        }
      })
    })    
    console.log('stream ids: ' + stream_ids);

    //TODO

  };
```

But when I try to log 'stream_ids' it's empty and nothing is shown. Properties stream_type and unit_price are not assigned.

I've tried promises but I haven't had success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an asynchronous issue. You're populating the value of the array inside a callback. But because of the nature of the event loop, it's impossible that any of the callbacks will have been called by the time the `console.log` is executed.

You mentioned a solution involving promises, and that's probably the right tack. For example something like the following:

```
exports = function(orgLoc_id, data) {
  // ...
  let stream_ids = [];
  const promises = data.map(function(stream) {
    return streamsCollection.findOne({ _id: stream.stream_id }, { type: 1, sizes: 1 })
      .then(res => { //if I comment this query it will push without any problem
        if (res) {
          let newId = new BSON.ObjectId();
          // ...
          stream_ids.push(newId);
        }
      })
  })

  Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    console.log('stream ids: ' + stream_ids);

    //TODO
    // any code that needs access to stream_ids should be in here...
  });
};
```

Note the change of `forEach` to `map`...that way you're getting an array of all the Promises (I'm assuming your `findOne` is returning a promise because of the `.then`).

Then you use a `Promise.all` to wait for all the promises to resolve, and then you should have your array.

Side note: A more elegant solution would involve returning `newId` inside your `.then`. In that case `Promise.all` will actually resolve with an array of the results of all the promises, which would be the values of `newId`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick! One quick question, if I want to make another query inside the last block of code and return something I should use resolve()?

I need something like this:

Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    console.log('stream ids: ' + stream_ids);

    return collection.find().toArray().then(res => {
         return res;
      })
  });

Thanks again!